# jquery event delegation on static content doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

JQuery event delegation not working on static content but work perfectly on dynamically added element. Alert('test') works perfectly on the dynamically added divs but not on static divs which are already present there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.addPost').on('click', function() {
          console.log("hello");

          var dyanamicdiv =
          '  <div>'+
          '      <div class="click-delgated-event">'+
          '          hello'+
          '      </div>'+
          '  </div>';

          $('.post-container').append(dyanamicdiv);

      });
      $('.post-container').on('click', '.click-delgated-event', function() {
        alert("test");
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-container">
    <div>
        <div class="click-delgated-event">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="addPost" type="button" name="button"> ADD POST </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `-` that you're missing on the static element class(in your code you have the static element with class like: `click-delgated event` and you're targeting an element with class `click-delgated-event` in your jQuery code):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addPost').on('click', function() {
    console.log("hello");

    var dyanamicdiv =
      '  <div>' +
      '      <div class="click-delgated-event">' +
      '          hello' +
      '      </div>' +
      '  </div>';

    $('.post-container').append(dyanamicdiv);

  });
  $('.post-container').on('click', '.click-delgated-event', function() {
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-container">
  <div>
    <div class="click-delgated-event">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="addPost" type="button" name="button"> ADD POST </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the `-` to your div class name

like below:

```
<div class="click-delgated-event">
   hello
</div>
```

you are by mistake `-` missing in your class name

so its work properly

Answer (score 0):

At `<div class="click-delgated event">` you missed `-` it should be

```
<div class="post-container">
    <div>
        <div class="click-delgated-event">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```